The Login button is only hidden and replaced by the Signout button after a hard refresh is performed
What I'm trying to implement is quite simple, I want to dynamically replace the login button in the navbar with a signout when the user logs in.
If there's a way to improve my implementation or if I've made a logical error, please feel free to correct it.
This is how I fetch user data
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchUser() {
    try {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
      if (error || !data?.user) {
        console.log("No user found")
      } else {
        setUser(data.user);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching user:", error);
    }
  }

  fetchUser();
}, []);

This is how I try to implement show and hide logic
{user ? (
  <form action="/auth/signout" method="post">
    <button className="mx-4 font-medium" type="submit">
      Sign out
    </button>
  </form>
) : (
  <Link className="mx-4 font-medium" href="/login">
    {" "}
    Login & Signup{" "}
  </Link>
)}

The two code blocks above are located in the header component.
The header component is located in the root layout.
I want to dynamically replace the login button in the navbar with a signout when the user logs in.

You should have a similar logic with useEffect after the login form triggers to fetch user data
